# Is there a way to run what's inside my update-function only on ButtonClick?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im building a 'timer', that goes from 0-13 in seconds, in Unity.
And I want to run what's inside my update function when I press a UI Button.
So far I have this;

```
    float tid = 0f;
    tid += Time.time;
    StingerSlider.value = tiden;
    if (StingerSlider.value == 13)
    {
        StingerSlider.value = 0;
    }
```

And since Im using Time.time or Time.deltaTime, which only works if its called every frame, how can I make this work?
Is there a simple method like if(Button.Clicked){do this} that I can have in my update function?

Comment: How many times do you want it to run?

Comment: Every time I press the button

Comment: What prevents you from using the [`onClick` button event?](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html)

Comment: Since my script is using Time.deltaTime that needs to run every frame

Comment: But you only want it to run when the button is clicked. Pick one or more clearly define your issue.

Comment: I just want to run the above script when my button is clicked

Comment: Again, what keeps you from using this inside an onClick event? `Time.deltaTime` is not magic that can only be called from `Update`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want it to run only when you *hold* down the button? Or do you want to click the button to toggle the timer?

I'll go ahead and assume you want the behavior to be toggle, in which case you would want to reference the button in your script, and add a listener to it that toggles a boolean when its clicked.

```
public class YourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Remember to attach your Button in the Inspector
    public Button mybutton;
    private bool toggle = false;

    void Start()
    {
        mybutton.onClick.AddListener(OnClick);
    }

    void OnClick()
    {
        toggle = !toggle;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(toggle)
        {
            // do your stuff that you want to do here!
        }
    }
}
```

The code in `Start()` is telling the button to perform the `OnClick()` function every time it is pressed, and then in `Update()` you are only executing your code when `toggle` is true.

Comment: I want to call the thing everytime I click the button, so its not actually a toggle, but this might work anyways?